# Node if/else statement using EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, passport-local

Could anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here? I'm a semi beginner coder, and looking to learn more. Im having an issue trying to use and if/else statement to change my header  to display "login" when a user is logged out, and "logout" when a user is logged in.

All my routes work fine, but just getting the logic right is giving me issues.
index.js

I have tried changing the "serializeduser" to "user" and a bunch of other things that wouldn't work for me.

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require("passport");
const passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");
const flash = require("flash");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));


app.use(session({
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false
}));


app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/userDB", {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
mongoose.set("useCreateIndex", true);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: String,
  password: String,
  googleId: String,
  secret: String
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);


const User = new mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});


app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.render("home");
});

app.get("/login", function(req, res) {
  res.render("login");
});

app.get("/register", function(req, res) {
  res.render("register");
});

app.get("/secrets", function(req, res) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    res.render("secrets");
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
});

app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.clearCookie();
  res.redirect('/');
});



app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
  successRedirect: '/secrets',
  failureRedirect: '/login',
  failureFlash: true,
}));


app.post("/register", function(req, res) {
  User.register({
    username: req.body.username
  }, req.body.password, function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("/");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function() {
        res.redirect("/secrets");
      });
    }
  });
});


app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000.");
});
```

header.ejs snippet

```
<% if ('serializeUser') { %>
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/login"> login</a></li>
<% } else { ('deserializeUser') %>
            <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">logout</a></li>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I can help you. But how can I know that a user is serialized or not in the backend? Because I don't know passport js. Please write a code to assign a variable true or false based on serialized or deserialized in the backend, then I can help you.

Comment: this is not how serialize and deserialize work. you should look for `user` variable in your layout.

Comment: @fedesc I tried looking for the user variable like this                                                               <% if ('user') { %>
        <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/login"> login</a></li>
<% } else { %>
            <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">logout</a></li>
<% } %>
 like this but still would not switch while logged in?